# RVM gem install directory when installing from git/github

Tags: ruby-on-rails, github, rubygems, rvm

I added a gem to my Rails Gemfile to be installed directly from the github source

```
gem 'redcarpet', github: 'tanoku/redcarpet'
...
bundle install
```

I use RVM and all my gems that get installed are in `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@my-gemset/gems`. However, I'm unable to see this new github gem there.

Do gems from github get installed elsewhere?

Answer (score 0):

Found it! Looks like since it installs a specific commit hash, it stores it in a different folder labeled with the commit hash as the "version"

```
~/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.2.2@my-gemset/bundler/gems/redcarpet-135b8e16b507
```